# User-defined settings for Facebook page tab?

Tags: facebook

I am developing a Facebook iframe application that requires some configuration for each install, such as long/lat and some third-party API keys.  I would rather not have to create a new app for each implementation.

Is there any way to allow the user (page owner) to define these settings?  Ideally, I'd like to provide additional settings in the "Edit Settings" dialog on the apps admin page (currently the only setting is "Custom Tab Name").

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but there is no easy/standard way to do this. I would try the following:

1. Your backend would need to provide the storage for each tab's settings; these would associate a specific tab with a specific page.
2. In your application's tab iframe add a link that only shows if the user viewing the tab is the user who is associated with the tab. You can do this by looking for the `page` value in the `signed_request` and making sure that the user is an admin.
3. When the user clicks that link, pop up the dialog to let them feed in the custom settings and save that on the server after performing the relevant validation.
4. On subsequent loads of the tab, look up and use the saved settings appropriately on your server.

You'll need to do some handling for situations where the page settings haven't yet been created, but that SHOULD do what you want.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but what I expected.  Thanks.

Comment: On the Facebook Integration tab of in the Facebook developers area, there is a field called "Edit URL."  Would that be more proper than adding a link that only shows for page admins as you suggest?

Comment: You can use that too: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153347/authenticating-administrative-users-in-settings-for-facebook-apps-embedded-in-pag for a description of possible usage. The issue with that is that you don't have control over where the link is displayed or what the link text says, so it may not be as obvious.

Comment: Cheers, this finally shed some light on the isse for me!